Spring for a library
I have written a library to provide a Java API for a Rest service with highly depending on spring / spring boot like RestTemplate, RestTemplateRequestCustomizer, ResponseErrorHandler, etc. I now want to distribute the library as jar so that it can be used in any Java application (also which does not use Spring) with maven or gradle by using the jar from a maven repository.
Library
build.gradle
plugins {
    id 'java-library'
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '3.3.2'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.1.6'
    id 'maven-publish'
}

group = 'com.example'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'

java {
    toolchain {
        languageVersion = JavaLanguageVersion.of(21)
    }
    withSourcesJar()
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

bootJar {
    enabled = true
}

jar {
    enabled = true
    archiveClassifier = ''
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
    testRuntimeOnly 'org.junit.platform:junit-platform-launcher'
}

publishing {
    publications {
        mavenJava(MavenPublication) {
            from components.java
        }
    }
}

The rest service
@Service
public class MyRestService {

    private final RestTemplate restTemplate;

    public MyRestService(RestTemplate restTemplate) {
        this.restTemplate = restTemplate;
    }

    public String getRandom() {
        return restTemplate.getForObject("https://httpbin.org/uuid", String.class);
    }
}

The configruation
@Configuration
public class LibraryConfig {

    @Bean
    public RestTemplate restTemplate(RestTemplateBuilder builder) {
        // a lot of customizations here. left for brevity
        return builder.build();
    }

}

Client
The client should just pull in the dependency
plugins {
    id 'java'
}

group = 'com.example'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'

java {
    toolchain {
        languageVersion = JavaLanguageVersion.of(21)
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenLocal()
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'com.example:library:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
}

And use it like this
package com.example.demo.client;

import com.example.demo.library.service.MyRestService;

public class ClientApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final MyRestService myRestService = new MyRestService(); // error: dependency RestTemplate is not available here
        System.out.println(myRestService.getRandom());
    }

}

Following issues are:

The client must add spring as dependency manually
The client does not have the library managed RestTemplate available for the consturctor argument of the MyRestService in ClientApplication.

Questions:

Does the client then have to deal with spring and start the spring container?
Is possible to make this transparent in the library or how this is usually solved?
Am I on the wrong track and is it necessary to tell the client that they can only use it with Spring applications?


You have asked the same question yesterday (Or the day before that). The comments already answered things and requested for more info. Posting the same question again without additional information isn't going to help.

I provided way more additional information regarding the questions from yesterday and NOT asked just the same as before.

Yes you did. The same 3 questions are in there, just some additional code. That isn't way more details in my book. You should have edited your original question.

My questions are still there because they are not answered, yes. I provided the information requested in the comments esp. "That is impossible to answer without knowing how you created your component." by providing code to address this.

But regardless, your client still will need to add a dependency on Spring, you either provide a fully configured RestTemplate by bootstrapping a context yourself or you allow this only to work within Spring based applications.

So you are saying it is not possible to do bootstrapping in the library and it's not possible to declare depenendencies for the library to spring in the pom in the maven repository in order the user does not have to add spring with the right version manually to the build file?

If you specify the correct dependency scope (api) that is automatically done and they don't need a version or dependency (which can lead to interesting results if they actually do have that). And yes you can do bootstrapping but then you would need to create a factory or sorts for your service to hide this.

Inspired by @M. Deinum comment I tried this:
Library
Declare spring as api dependency and make sure pom contains the dependency.
dependencies {
    api 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
    testRuntimeOnly 'org.junit.platform:junit-platform-launcher'
}

publishing {
    publications {
        mavenJava(MavenPublication) {
            from components.java
            versionMapping {
                usage('java-api') {
                    fromResolutionOf('runtimeClasspath')
                }
                usage('java-runtime') {
                    fromResolutionResult()
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

Add a new class that bootstraps spring, gets the constructed service from the application and delegates to the service.
public class MyRestServiceApi implements GetRandom {

    @Override
    public String getRandom() {
        // Create the application context with the configuration class
        AnnotationConfigApplicationContext context = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(LibraryApplication.class);

        MyRestService myRestService = context.getBean(MyRestService.class);

        String random = myRestService.getRandom();

        context.close();
        return random;
    }
}

Client
Use the service
package com.example.demo.client;

import com.example.demo.library.api.MyRestServiceApi;

public class ClientApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final MyRestServiceApi myRestServiceApi = new MyRestServiceApi();
        System.out.println(myRestServiceApi.getRandom());
    }

}

Requesting feedback and comments for this approach.

Don't ask a new question in an answer. Also for code reviews use https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ instead of stackoverflow.
